# AWS ElasticBeanstalk Docker - How to execute shell script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've create a docker image that houses a jar file. I'd like to deploy this to ElasticBeanstalk and execute the jar via a sh file. I've tried to do this by setting the `Entrypoint` to "/bin/sh" in my `Dockerrun.aws.json` file, and the `Command` to `/app/dockerrun.sh`. This works when ssh into the box, build an image from the `/var/app/current` directory, and run it manually-

```
cd /var/app/current
sudo docker build -t "test" .
sudo docker run --entrypoint /bin/sh test /app/dockerrun.sh
```

But it doesn't work when I deploy this `Dockerrun.aws.json` file-

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Image": {
    "Name": "...",
    "Update": true
  },
  "Ports": [{
    "ContainerPort": 8080
  }],
  "Volumes": [{
      "HostDirectory": "/var/app/current",
      "ContainerDirectory": "/app"
  }],
  "Logging": "/var/log",
  "Entrypoint": "/bin/sh",
  "Command": "/app/dockerrun.sh"
}
```

I get the following 2 lines (and only those 2 lines) from `/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/unexpected-quit.log`

> Docker container quit unexpectedly on Thu Aug  8 22:09:47 UTC 2019:
>
> /bin/sh: 0: Can't open /app/dockerrun.sh

And if I attempt to run the it through `sudo /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/00run.sh` i get-

> sudo /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/00run.sh
>
> Docker container quit unexpectedly after launch: Docker container quit unexpectedly on Thu Aug  8 22:16:09 UTC 2019:
>
> /bin/sh: 0: Can't open /app/dockerrun.sh. Check snapshot logs for details.
>
> No environment variable EB_EVENT_FILE found.    Writing message to stderr.
>
> Msg: Docker container quit unexpectedly after launch: Docker container quit unexpectedly on Thu Aug  8 22:16:09 UTC 2019:
>
> /bin/sh: 0: Can't open /app/dockerrun.sh. Check snapshot logs for details.

Why can't I run my dockerrun.sh file with the method given?